# Read file, extract url and re-write -Python

Tags: python, url

I'm reading text file in the following `format(a.txt)`.

http://www.example.com/forum/showthread.php?t=779689/images/webcard.jpg 121.10.208.31

Then I need to obtain only the `www.example.com` part with `/images/webcard.jpg 121.10.208.31` and write to the same file or a separate one. In this case I'm writing it to `b.txt`.

```
from urlparse import urlparse 
f = open('a.txt','r')
fo = open('b','w')


for line in f:
    fo.write(urlparse(line).netloc+ ' ' + line.split(' ')[1] + ' ' + line.split(' ')[2] + '\n')
```

the above code gives the following error?How to achieve this?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prittyprint.py", line 17, in <module>
    fo.write(urlparse(line).netloc+ ' ' + line.split(' ')[1] + ' ' + line.split(' ')[2] + '\n')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: maybe there are exceptions in your file `a.txt`? some line might not have this format. Can you print the line where it crashes?

Comment: In code what does variable 'line' refer to ?

Comment: @sateesh : I have edited it..Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

It could be that there are exceptions in your file `a.txt`. Some line(s) might not have this format.   You can try this -

```
from urlparse import urlparse 

f = open('a.txt','r')
fo = open('b','w')

for line in f:
    split_line = line.split(' ')
    if len(split_line) >=3:
        fo.write(urlparse(line).netloc+ ' ' + split_line[1] + ' ' + split_line[2] + '\n')
    else:
        print "ERROR: some other line: %s" % (line) #continue on with next line
```

Comment: It prints Error message for all the lines in a.txt?

Comment: then there is something wrong. Can you show the exact line where the crash happens? are all the lines of the format `http://www.example.com/forum/showthread.php?t=779689 /images/webcard.jpg 121.10.208.31` ?

Comment: Yes,each line is in same format and has three blocks seperated by spaces...I used try: statement? Then it worked?for line in f:
    split_line = line.split(' ')
    try:
       fo.write(urlparse(line).netloc+ ' ' + split_line[1] + ' ' + split_line[2] + '\n')
    except: 
      pass........but this is not perfect isn’t it?

Comment: ofcourse not! all you are doing is simply ignoring the error cases since you are doing `pass` in `except:`. This makes your program crash proof :)

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot..I'll try to figure about the problem with my text file.

Comment: Already I have up voted your answer and comment..:)if len(split_line) >=3: Actually there was a line <3 splits.